# FFT Data - How to get frequencies?

Tags: fft, python

I have some python code running an FFT on EEG data, I now want to be able to read frequencies, for example something like `x = fftdata(10hz - 50hz)`. This is my code so far:

```
streams = resolve_stream('type', 'EEG')
inlet = StreamInlet(streams[0])

sample, timestamp = inlet.pull_sample()
data.append(sample[2])

fftdata = abs(scipy.fft.fft(data))
freqs = fftpk.fftfreq(len(FFT), (1.0/s_rate))
```

What would be a simple way to do this?
Any help much appreciated :)

Comment: `fftfreq` gives you the frequency that corresponds to each index. That is, read the values of `fftdata` for which the corresponding values of `fftfreq` are between 10 and 50.

Comment: @MBaz Could you please provide an example? Thank You!